# How to use strictNullChecks with libraries that are not nullCheck safe

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I feel like I am missing something big here.  I have read all the details of the new strictNullCheck goodness in [typescript 2.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/07/11/announcing-typescript-2-0-beta/).  I would love to use it but when I turn it on in my projects it finds issues with the supporting libraries I am using and their associated type definitions.

I can change my code to have sound type definitions but I don't have an easy way to update all the other libraries I use.  Does this effectively mean that I can't use strictNullCheck until/unless the libraries I am using update to be strict null safe?

Comment: Can you list the supporting libraries in the `exclude` parameter of the `tsconfig.json`

Comment: After looking into this more it looks like there is no way to do this.  You can't use type definitions that don't support strict null and turn on strict null checking without running into issues.  The recommendation is to fix the issue and submit a PR back to definitelytyped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking around for quite a while I finally found that by using the compiler option `skipDefaultLibCheck` you can get most of what I needed here.

Comment: You can override a type declaration use `baseUrl` and `paths` to map it to another declaration file.