# Is there a way to only enable strictNullChecks for non-library code?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I've enabled `strictNullChecks` for my TypeScript application. I am using RxJS 5, which is written in TypeScript. It, however, has not enabled `strictNullChecks`.

Hence, when I do the following:

```
Observable.fromEvent(document.getElementById('button'), 'click')
```

I get the following error:

```
Error TS2345: Argument of type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventTargetLike'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'EventTargetLike'.
```

In other words, when RxJS [says](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/observable/FromEventObservable.ts#L56) the first argument should be an `EventTargetLike`, what it actually means is that it should be roughly an `EventTargetLike | null` - which is what it is, when using their TypeScript configuration.

Is there a way to get TypeScript to use a library's config when available (i.e. without turning off type checking alltogether, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39620788/how-to-use-strictnullchecks-with-libraries-that-are-not-nullcheck-safe), and which doesn't work for non-default libraries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what it actually means is that it should be roughly an EventTargetLike | null

Probably not. It actually wants a target and you should not pass something that might be null. Quick fix :

```
let btn = document.getElementById('button');
Observable.fromEvent(btn!, 'click');
```

Where you are telling the compiler with `!` that *I know btn to not be null*. Alternatively you can do the check to make the compiler happy:

```
let btn = document.getElementById('button');
if (btn != null){
  Observable.fromEvent(btn, 'click');
}
```

Comment: Actually, it does check whether the target is something unexpected like null: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/observable/FromEventObservable.ts#L138

That said, I guess you are right that I probably want to do that check myself already, and deal with that in a graceful way. So thanks for the pointers on how to do that :)